# javascript replace node and all of it childs with anothe code

Tags: javascript, html

How can you replace HTML tag with all tags branching inside using Javascript with other HTML code?
example:

```
<div class="a">
<div class="sub-a1">
    <div class="sub-a12">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-a2">
    <div class="sub-b">

    </div>
</div>
```

I wanna replace all tags from tag div class 'a' including all sub nodes with another code.
is that's possible?
please help me.

Comment: First: what code do you want to insert in place of the code that's removed? What's your expected end-result? Second: when you started to solve this problem what did you come up with? What went wrong? Show your "*[mcve]*" code, that way we can hopefully offer some guidance and advice to help you learn and improve.

Comment: When someone answer your question, what should you do -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```js
const target = document.querySelector(".a");
target.innerHTML = //place your html here as string
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. If you want to keep the div.a elements and just change the "subnodes" you have to use innerHTML in stead of outerHTML.

```
const divs = [...document.getElementsByClassName("a")]; //make a copy of the HTML collection so that they can be removed without being removed in the array
const newElement = "<h1>Replaced Element</h1>"; //this is your replacement element
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { // loop through all the divs
    divs[i].outerHTML = newElement; // set the outer html for the div to the replacement elemzent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `.replaceWith()` with a valid HTML code.

```js
function replace() {
var para = document.createElement("P");               // Create a <p> element
para.innerText = "This is a paragraph";               // Insert text
document.querySelector(".a").replaceWith(para);

}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="sub-a1">
    <div class="sub-a12">
      <h4>Sample content1</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-a2">
    <div class="sub-b">
      <h4>Sample content2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<button onclick="replace();"/>Click to Replace</button>
```